# TYPO3 Upgrade Psr Problem vom 10.x to 11.5.8,

Tags: typo3, upgrade, extbase

I tried to upgrade from 10.x to 11.5.8 and nothing was working anymore. If I try to open the url I recieve the following error message:
`Fatal error: Declaration of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController::processRequest(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request, TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface $response) must be compatible with TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ControllerInterface::processRequest(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\RequestInterface $request): Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\extbase\Classes\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php on line 243`

So the next step was to disable all my extensions.
If I try to open the backend, I recieve the same message as above.

The next step was to use the Install Tool, which was working. But if I try to use some functions like "Upgrade Wizard", "Analyze Database Structure", "
Remove Temporary Assets", ....
[image]

But the sys_log and the log files under `typo3temp` are empty!

And also the firefox degugger is not showing any information.

PHP 7.4.15, no composer installation and chaches all deleted!

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

The first error message says that there are Extbase extensions which are not compatible with v11. See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-92502-MakeExtbaseHandlePSR7ResponsesOnly.html

For the second error I'd recommend to look into the dev console of your browser. There you might see more information about the error when there is nothing in the logs. (Maybe there is an error when writing log?)

Comment: Thomas, I knw this from another installation. But I have all extensions deleted and ereased from PackageStates.php. That's what confused me.

Comment: Cleared cache? Opcode cache as well?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned file "AbstractController.php" exists only in version 10 and was removed afterwards.
So TYPO3 is using some old files, probably from the file-cache.
You wrote that you use an installation without composer-setup. Those installations have the file-cache saved in `typo3temp/var/cache`. This folder can be deleted completely and will be rebuilt automatically.
Afterwards TYPO3 version 11 should run and the error-message should never be shown again.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my experiences with updating TYPO3 to a new mayor release, i did the following steps.

- Renamed fileadmin dir
- Deleted all TYPO3 dirs
- Installed the new version of TYPO3
- Start TYPO3 from scratch with an new database (use the ID and passwort from the final database, use the right sitename)
- Rename the fileadmin dir back to fileadmin
- Go into LocalConfiguration.php and switch under DB to the original database
- (Maybe) enable 'debug' => true, for BE and FE and set 'displayErrors' => 1, under SYS
- Try to start the BE, if failed go to the Install tool.
- Start Upgrade Wizard under Upgrade
- In the Install tool start the Analyze Database Structure, but be carefull. that you dont't delete any database of your extensions, which not installed yet!

Now the BE should work now and you can upgrade your extensions!

Good Look.